# Magento 2.1.7 can't see menu block when full page cache is on

Tags: magento, caching, magento2

I've problem with my magento menu block is gone and I've noticed when I turn off full page cache it's back.

Flushed all cache inside magento admin but it did not help.

Block is enabled and I have no idea what else I can do I did:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

On cli
Any ideas ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Oh sorry is there any chance to move that question on the right place then?

Comment: No, you should just go there an post this question. It's not hard to re-post yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in the past and in my case this was due to non deployed theme. Try running this before deploying the static content (replacing the default theme with the one you are using).

```
php bin/magento dev:source-theme:deploy --theme Magento/luma --locale en_GB
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it's still the same maybe I should run those commands in different order? I did run your before deployment what about the others? Should that make a difference ? Thansk

Comment: Are you assuming the theme and locale here?

Comment: @ nikos83 for the order should be correct to just run it before the static-content:deploy, please have a look if you have some errors in the logs.

@RobbieAverill yes, you need to replace the theme and locale depending on what you want to deploy